# Attribute not being serialized on custom ArrayList extending class

Tags: java, attributes, simple-framework

Here's my problem, I have a class `A` like this :

```
class A {
    public A(MyList myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    @ElementList(name = "MyList", entry = "MyListElement", type = MyListElement.class)
    private MyList myList;

    // getters, setters ...
}
```

And I have my `MyList` class which is a particular `ArrayList` :

```
class MyList extends ArrayList<MyListElement> {

    public MyList(Long attribute) {
        this.myListAttribute = attribute;
    }

    @Attribute(name = "MyListAttribute")
    private Long myListAttribute;

    // getters, setters ...
}
```

So here, my element list needs an attribute to be provided. I found out that it was the solution (extending ArrayList<> class), or maybe I'm wrong ?

The problem is that, everything works well and is serialized the way I want, even the MyListElement which contains attributes, and many elements, except **the `MyList` attribute**

I get something like this when I try to serialize :

```
<A>
    <MyList>  <!-- Here the attribute is missing... -->
         <MyListElement Att1="X" Att2="Something" Att3="Blabla">
             <AnElement>Test</AnElement>
             <AnotherElement>Test2</AnotherElement>
         </MyListElement>
    </MyList>
</A>
```

I think I've missed something in the documentation, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you're expecting? What attribute are you missing? As far as I can tell, your serialized XML block doesn't match the class definitions above.

Comment: What I expect is that <MyList> appears as :
<MyList MyListAttribute="...">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found another way to do what I want.
Maybe I was doing wrong or maybe the framework does not look the attributes set on an `@ElementList` property.

So I transformed my `MyList` class like this :

```
class MyList { // notice it does not extend ArrayList<MyListElement> anymore

    // Now I set this list in inline mode
    @ElementList(entry = "MyListElement", type = MyListElement.class, inline = true)
    private ArrayList<MyListElement> elementList;

    @Attribute(name = "MyListAttribute")
    private Long attribute;
}
```

and in my `class A`:

```
class A {
   @Element(name = "MyList")
   private MyList myList;
}
```

That way, I get what I expect :

```
<A>
    <MyList MyListAttribute="...">
        <MyListElement></MyListElement>
    </MyList>
</A>
```